# Помогите написать код на php

Tags: php

я хочу сделать так,чтобы при нажатии на категорию,выводились все статьи с это категорией.
Т.к я новичок в php,то я не понимаю как это осуществить)

Ссылки с категориями:[image: категории]

Подскажите пожалуйста какой нибудь способ это осуществить)

бд статьей
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CDd5.png

бд категорий
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLwhM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй библиотеку mysqli https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php Я б сделал так, у тебя будет отдельная страницы для всех категорий, на этих страницах используешь смешанный код html + php

Пример можешь посмотреть здесь https://github.com/GlushkovIS/blog/blob/master/index.php

Кратко так:
Подключаешься к БД

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER,PASS, DB);
```

получаешь ответ на запрос к БД с нужными статьями

```
$request = "select * from запрос к БД";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $request);
```

вывод статей на странице

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {?>
    <div class="section">
        <h1><span><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></span></h1>
        <br>
        <p>
            <?php echo $row["content"]; }?>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое

Comment: только эта ссылка не рабочая https://github.com/GlushkovIS/blog/blob/master/index.php

Comment: нзч, сделал репозиторий публичным, теперь должно быть ок)

Comment: ссылка работает,спасибо)